# TS2304: Cannot find name 'Map' in node 5.1.0, typescript 1.6.2, webstorm 11

Tags: node.js, typescript, ecmascript-6, webstorm

when using the filewatchers in webstorm 11 i got an TS2304-error for ts-compiler 1.62.

TS2304: Cannot find name 'Map'

deactivating the filewatcher and using the command

```
tsc --target es6 app.ts
```

in the directory works well but i want to have the automatisation.

i tried:

```
tsd install node
```

without any effect.

what can i do?

Comment: why don't you use built-in typescript compiler? it works much better than file watchers. Also, do you have Map definition available in your project? How is it referenced from your code? When compiling in command line, do you use tsconfig.json?

Comment: i think so, but i am a beginner in typescript / ecma6. i installed the stuff and it worked but i did not configure the tsconfig.json by myself.

Comment: not enough information to figure out the problem, sorry. I'd suggest creating a support ticket, providing your project to support

Answer (score 0):

In webstorm go into preferences or settings click `Languages & Frameworks > Typescript` then in `Default options:` add `--lib es6`

Alternatively if you have a `tsconfig.json` and your problematic file is in the `"included"` array you can add `"es6"` to the `"lib"` array.